# Making Scala code interoperable with a Java library

Tags: java, scala

I have a Java library that I have to use / call and I'm doing that from Scala. The Java library has a signature like this:

```
JavaFunction( List<Object[]> data) {
  this.data = data;
}
```

I was under the assumption that to be compatible with this from Scala, I need to have a AnyRef, so I had this defined:

```
  val fromScala: List[Array[AnyRef]] = List(
    Array[AnyRef](1, "Str1", 'a'),
    Array[AnyRef](2, "Str2", 'b'),
    Array[AnyRef](3, "Str3", 'c'),
    Array[AnyRef](4, "Str4", 'd')
  )
```

When I tried to pass this to the constructor, upon compilation, I hit the following error:

```
the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
    Array[AnyRef](1,  "Str1", 'a')
```

I understand that the compiler is expecting that I should be explicit on my types, but I do not see any other way to make this compatible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `1` those are `AnyVal` instead of `AnyRef` thus an implicit conversion happens under the hood.

You may use `Int.box(1)` to create a `java.lang.Integer`
However, that boxing will nevertheless happen at runtime so you are only adding boilerplate, you may try to see if `List[Array[Any]]` compiles and works as expected.

Comment: Spot on! But I thought AnyRef is the Scala equivalent of Java's Object which made me think that I should be using AnyRef instead of Any.

Comment: @joesan AFAIK it technically is, but well `Any` also has to erase to that; but I wasn't sure and I couldn't test. I am glad it worked :D

Comment: It's a bit more complicated - `AnyRef` is about all `Object`s _except_ primitive wrappers and `void` counterpart (`Unit` is `AnyVal`). That's because `AnyVal`s are converted to primitives OR wrappers depending on the context. So when you are interacting with Java you should manually convert your types to Java types - AnyVal and AnyRef is not 100% mapable to primitive or `Object`, so it's better to make this convertion yourself or use `Any` and let Scala decide.